# Declare class definition separately from class implementation

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript2.6

Ok so I have a multi-codebase project

I have a class in codebase P1:

```
class ClassInP1 {


}
```

but I need the type of that class to be referenced in another codebase P2, but I don't want to install P1 as dependency of P2. **To be clear**: P1 imports P2, but I do not want P2 to import P1!

Is the best way to do this, to create an interface in P2 and have `ClassInP1` implement that interface? Like so:

```
import {InterfaceFromP2} from 'P2';

class ClassInP1 implements InterfaceFromP2 {



}
```

the only annoying thing about that, is that it's not 100% DRY..the class would be pretty much self-documenting, but then I have duplicate a lot of that in the interface, but I guess that's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I'm using namespaces here to create a stand-alone demonstration - the namespaces demonstrate the concept, but are not needed to make any of this work.

TypeScript is beautifully structural in nature, which means the names only matter insofar as they identify something within a naming context. When it comes to using types, they just have to be compatible (have the required structure).

```
namespace A {
    export class ExampleOne {
        name: string;
        size: number;
    }
}

namespace B {
    export class ExampleOne {
        name: string;
        size: number;
    }

    export class ExampleTwo {
        name: string;
        size: number;
        volume: number;
    }
}

function logExample(example: A.ExampleOne) {
    console.log(example.name);
}

logExample(new A.ExampleOne());

logExample(new B.ExampleOne());

logExample(new B.ExampleTwo());
```

I can re-use the name `ExampleOne` in any naming context (namespace, module).

I can pass any value that is compatible with `A.ExampleOne` into the `logExample` function. It doesn't have to be the exact class, or a subclass, or even a class - as long as is structurally compatible.

So you can have

```
class ClassInP1

}
```

Without inheriting from the original `ClassInP1`, and without creating an interface.

Comment: I read this a couple times, and I am having trouble understanding how it relates to the OP. If you can use the same class names as the OP, that would help I think. If namespaces aren't necessary to answer the question, maybe drop them from the answer? dunno

Comment: one thing - I am not sure how to define prototype methods without actually implementing them in a class - I guess you can use `typeof` perhaps to do that?

Comment: yeah you've made a point, as long as something adheres to an interface, it doesn't actually have to have the right name in the hierarchy - it can have any name. But unfortunately this doesn't prevent me from having to implement the class/interface twice.

Comment: @AlexanderMills you can also create an abstract class, with an abstract method if you want to provide a class definition with no implementation - if you do extend it with another class, it will help you to keep the contact.